# Can I do REST API testing in LeanFT and have test results updated in HP ALM?

Tags: hp-uft, hp-alm, leanft

I found that API testing is supported by UFT. What about LeanFT. I know I could do the testing with help of some Java libraries, but I am not sure if test results can be updated in HP ALM. What is the trick here?
Can I or cannot do the API testing with LeanFT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LeanFT is relying on an SDK (Java, C#, JavaScript, etc.)

Any of those SDK already have plenty of ways to do REST API tests, so LeanFT didn't implement a way to do that. (It would mean to reinvent the wheel).

Your question really is: can you report results to ALM through LeanFT?
And you can do that, of course. Here's [one example](https://eyeonquality.com/how-to-view-hpe-leanft-test-results-in-hpe-alm/), out of [many others](https://www.google.com/search?q=LeanFT+HP+ALM+reporting&oq=LeanFT+HP+ALM+reporting).